# BCE0051: Operator '<' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'Object' and a right hand side of type 'float'

Tags: android, unityscript

pls..can anyone tell how to fix this error...

PLSSSSSSS HELP...

BCE0051: Operator '<' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'Object' and a right hand side of type 'float'.

```
     if (doorCheckingNow.GetComponent(AIpathDoorScript).doorsToCells[i]< shortestPathSoFar)
```

Comment: What does your `doorsToCells` contain? Are you comparing apples and `4.327`?

Comment: Not what `doorsToCells` *is* (I guessed it from `doorsToCells[i]`); what does it *contain*? What's in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object : - `doorCheckingNow.GetComponent(AIpathDoorScript).doorsToCells[i]`

Float : - `shortestPathSoFar`

What you are doing : - `if(Object<float)`

It's like you are comparing if "SFDDSFSD" is less than 5. Understood ?

Comment: okk...I understand..
but can you tell me correct code...because i'm really a noob.. :(

Comment: For doing that we need to know your full code and a full explanation to exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are making a comparison between an Object and a float. This would be similar to asking the question: "is paper less than 5"? In other words, this comparison doesn't make sense.

Maybe you should be comparing some property of `doorCheckingNow.GetComponent(AIpathDoorScript).doorsToCells[i]` (that is a number) with `shortestPathSoFar`?

Comment: okk...I understand..
but can you tell me correct code...because i'm really a noob.. :(